# MySQL: update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What I want to do is compare two tables, and perform an update in tableb where column doesn't match the same column.

I know in SQL this is

```
update tableb
   set myInt = 1
 where tableA.Column <> tableb.column
```

How is this done is MySQL?

Basically all I want to do is where tableA doesn't have the same value in tableB update tableB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE tableB 
   SET tableB.MyInt = 1 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                     FROM tablea a
                    WHERE a.column = TableB.Column)
```

...which can also be written as:

```
   UPDATE TABLE_B
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A ON TABLE_A.COLUMN = TABLE_B.COLUMN
      SET TABLE_B.myint = 1
    WHERE TABLE_A.COLUMN IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables.

```
UPDATE tableB 
INNER JOIN tableA on (TableA.id = TableB.id) 
SET tableB.MyInt = 1 WHERE TableA.`Column` != TableB.`Column`
```

A join on matching id's seems logical, because a

```
JOIN tableA on (tableA.`column` != tableB.`column`)
```

will do something a lot like a cross join, probably not what you'd expect.

Note that `column` is a reserved word in MySQL and needs to be enclosed in backticks: `` ` ``

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a join.

```
UPDATE TABLEB
FROM TABLEB
INNER JOIN TABLEA ON TABLEA.COLUMN!=TABLEB.COLUMN
SET myINT=1
```

Comment: Also note that `column` is a reserved word and should be enclosed in backticks '`'.

Comment: Column here was just a generic term.

Answer (score -1):

The operator is `!=` not `<>`

Try this.

```
update tableb set myInt = 1 where tableA.Column!=tableb.column
```

Edit: Oops I completely overlooked the join part. Look the response below this one.